# How to make Pnp function async in spfx framework

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp-js-core

I need to get data from a function as below.

```
GetServiceListData():any  
  { 
    var resultData;
    pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle('Test').items.select('Title,FullName,DOJ,ManagerName/Title').expand('ManagerName').get(asy).then(function(data) {
      resultData= data;
    });
}
```

This method is calling synchronous in which I am unable to get the data in the first time when trying to call in other function. How we can make a pnp function to call async?

Glad for any help..

Answer (score 3):

You need to ensure that your function is `async`. Only if its `async` can you use `await` inside that function.

You can modify the below code:

```
private async GetServiceListData():any  
{ 
    var resultData: any = await pnp.sp.web.lists
                               .getByTitle('Test')
                               .items                                     
                               .select('Title,FullName,DOJ,ManagerName/Title')
                               .expand('ManagerName').get();    

    //do something with the data
    console.log(resultData);
}
```

Reference - [Typescript Async/Await](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/async-await.html)

Answer (score 3):

As i understand your question, you need to handle the response data outside of given function. In this case you can simply return the pnp func call, so it returns a Promise:

```
function GetServiceListData():Promise<any>  
{ 
    return pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle('Test').items
        .select('Title,FullName,DOJ,ManagerName/Title')
        .expand('ManagerName')
        .get();
}
function successCallback(response){
    //do things with response in a callback
}
function errorCallback(error){
    //handle error
}
//usage
GetServiceListData()
    .then(successCallback)
    .catch(errorCallback);
```

If you want to do some preprocessing with the response data first, you have two options.

First you can go with async function to flattern out your function for readability

```ts
async function GetServiceListData():Promise<any>
{ 
    let preprocessedData;
    let response;
    try {
        response = await pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle('Test').items
        .select('Title,FullName,DOJ,ManagerName/Title')
        .expand('ManagerName')
        .get();

        //do things with response in place
    } catch(error) {
        //handle error
    }

    //do things with response in place
    return preprocessedData;
}
```

Or you can still use the Thenable format. In this case you need to return the preprocessed data inside the `.then`

```
function GetServiceListData():Promise<any>  
{ 
    return pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle('Test').items
        .select('Title,FullName,DOJ,ManagerName/Title')
        .expand('ManagerName')
        .get()
        .then(response => {
            let preprocessedData;
            //do things with response
            return preprocessedData;
        });
}
```

Important to notice, that in all cases, you are returning a `Promise`, so you can use the `.then` and `.catch` methods to do stuff with the data outside `GetServiceListData`.

[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

[Async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)